# How to do css style for ordered list numbers?

Tags: html, css

I try to change the style of the Ordered list numbers using CSS, but I got some wrong outcomes.

```
<ol>
  <li>This is the first item</li>
  <li>This is the second item</li>
  <li>This is the third item</li>
  <li>This is the fourth item</li>
  <li>This is the fifth item</li>
  <li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(0,200,200);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

The above code displays 2 List numbers (One Default and the other is my defined style). The output is like

1. 1. This is my first item
2. 2. This is my second item

So, why it occurs double times. Please help to get that as single time (the second one is my defined style)

Comment: Here is my codepen link https://codepen.io/pahalavan-r-d/pen/MNJgqN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`custom-counter` is an invalid selector and even if it was valid, it would be pointing to nothing. Just remove that whole ruleset and then add `list-style-type: none;` to the `<ol>` as in:

```
ol {list-style-type: none;}
```

Assign `position:relative` to all `<li>` and `position:absolute` to each `li::before` in order to have granular control over all bullet distances from text.

```
li {
  position: relative;
...
}

li::before {
...
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  /* Adjust < -number | number+ > */
  left: -32px;
...
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1.25 Verdana
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  /* Adjust < -number | number+ > */
  left: -32px;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 200);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>This is the first item</li>
  <li>This is the second item</li>
  <li>This is the third item</li>
  <li>This is the fourth item</li>
  <li>This is the fifth item</li>
  <li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Ok, the first list numbers are disappeared. But the second list numbers remain in the same position. It has to come to the position as the first list numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution for styling <li> numbers: put a <span> around the entire content within each <li>, then style the <span> differently than the <li> itself.

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
<li><span>List item</span></li>
<li><span>List item</span></li>
<li><span>List item</span></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li span {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```